# Binding images with v-html

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array with some object and each object has an image tag, so i want to show this images but i dont know how i think the mistake is in the src of image..
Its my code in file in folder components its
Template :

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
 <div v-html="item.image"></div>
</div>
```

And its script

```
data(){
 return {
  items: [
    {title : 'IMG1', image : '<img src="../assets/img1.jpg" alt="None">',},
    {title : 'IMG2', image : '<img src="../assets/img2.jpg" alt="None">',}
  ]
 }
}
```

But its just show None.. please how can i get this images?!
its my folder directory im in file posts.vue and i wanna get images in assets/images

[image]

Comment: `import images from "../assets/*.*"` use like `image : '<img :src="images.img1.jpg" alt="None">'`

Comment: dont place html in the model, instead just the file path/name `image : 'img1.jpg'`, it will make it much simpler

Comment: That's gave me error, Module not found: Error can't resolve '../assets'

Comment: do a sanity check where the folder is located (or show us your directory structure with a tree cmd or a screen), its not ../assets relative to the build path/component or http request.

Comment: A while back, I had same issue, prob not a dupe but may be of some interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963030/parcel-js-vue-dynamic-images-src/58712521#58712521

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Comment: I added an image of my directory folder

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using an image tag? Like `<img :src="item.image" alt="none" />`. and have your image in data as just a string like `"../assets/img1.jpg"`.