# Vue don't load dynamic src and require doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a problem, I want to show a dynamic img but if i write like this :
`<img :src="src" alt="img">` 
It doesn't work,

instead it works if i do :
`<img src="../assets/img/banana.png" alt="img">`

I've already tried whit require but it returns an error :
`Error: Cannot find module '../assets/img/banana.png'"`

Comment: import the images, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963030/parcel-js-vue-dynamic-images-src/58712521#58712521

Comment: it returns    Error: Cannot find module '../assets/img/*.png'

Comment: maybe your path is wrong.. https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-bird-9py2v?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: actually I just checked and `*` doesn't seem to work with vue-cli :( must be a parceljs thing :) I just checked and `<img width="25%" :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')">` works fine.

Comment: it doesn't work   https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-shape-2y4zp?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: summing is up with codesandbox, getting *Error in render: "Error: /src/assets/pokedex.png hasn't been transpiled yet."* which after like 2mins goes away, also is not working in ./img folder but works fine up one folder which is sucky, dunno, your paths are good, use `:src="require(test.img)"` like the example above and sometimes it works ;p

Comment: is working now (no changes).. https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-dawn-rj4yz?file=/src/data/projects.js

Comment: The images must be on your public folder

Comment: @AndersonIvanWitzke no they dont

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You are correct... I found it out later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no information about where the module is located and webpack cannot resolve it.

> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as
> import(foo). Because foo could potentially be any path to any file in
> your system or project.
>
> The import() must contain at least some information about where the
> module is located.

To fix this, you can create a BaseImage component that replaces the dynamic sources that start with a certain path, in this case `../assets/`, and let webpack know that information beforehand.

ie.

```
<template>
  <img
    :src="computedSrc"
    :alt="alt"
    class="BaseImage"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseImage',

  inheritAttrs: false,

  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    /**
     * The alt tag is required for accessibility and SEO purposes.
     *
     * If it is a decorative image, which is purely there for design reasons,
     * consider moving it to CSS or using an empty alt tag.
     */
    alt: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    // If the URL starts with ../assets/, it will be interpreted as a module request.
    isModuleRequest() {
      return this.src.startsWith('../assets/')
    },

    computedSrc() {
      // If it is a module request,
      // the exact module is not known on compile time,
      // so an expression is used in the request to create a context.
      return this.isModuleRequest
        ? require(`../assets/${this.src.replace('../assets/', '')}`)
        : this.src
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

Replace `img` with the `BaseImage` component.

```
<!-- <img :src="img.src"  :alt="img.alt"> -->
<BaseImage :src="img.src" :alt="img.alt"/>
```

### [Revised codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-pond-remyi)